# trilinos does not install pytrilinos

Tags: python, pytrilinos, trilinos

I have compiled trilinos with pytrilinos but python does not import PyTrilinos.

This is what i have done, I configure the packages to install

```
cd Trilinos-build
cmake -D Trilinos_ENABLE_PyTrilinos:BOOL=ON -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -D Trilinos_ENABLE_ALL_OPTIONAL_PACKAGES:BOOL=ON ../trilinos-11.8.1-Source
```

Then I installed with make

```
cd Trilinos-build
make -j1 install
```

But when I try to use PyTrilinos, python says ther is no module

```
python
>>> from PyTrilinos import Epetra
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyTrilinos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that came out was to install the library in $HOME/trilinos-install

```
cd $home
mkdir trilinos-{install,build}
cd trilinos-build

cmake \
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RELEASE \
  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:STRING="$HOME/trilinos-install" \
  -D TPL_ENABLE_MPI:BOOL=ON \
  -D Trilinos_ENABLE_ALL_OPTIONAL_PACKAGES:BOOL=ON \
  ../trilinos-11.8.1-Source
```

after that tell to python where is the modules

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/trilinos-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and specify where is installed pytrilinos a its libraries

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/trilinos-install/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then install with  make

```
cd Trilinos-build
make -j1 install
```

and finally the module is recognized by python

```
python
>>> from PyTrilinos import Epetra
```